# How to solve syntax error with git clone code?

Tags: python-3.x, git, command-line, python-idle

I'm python beginner and have issues with running a the following command:

```
git clone https://github.com/marksgraham/OCT-Converter.git
```

(https://github.com/marksgraham/OCT-Converter)

I have installed Python 3.7.4 on my mac and tied to run this in the IDLE. But it says "SyntaxError: invalid syntax" regarding "clone". Do I need to install something else first to be able to run this?

Comment: you have to install [git](https://git-scm.com/downloads)

Comment: Interactive python is for executing python statements, not OS command lines.  If you start python from a command line, you will see the same error.  IDLE's Shell simulates interactive python quite closely.

Answer (score 9):

you just need to '!' before the command

Your command would be like,

```
!git clone https://github.com/marksgraham/OCT-Converter.git
```

NOTE : if you are using anaconda navigator or googlecolab

Answer (score 1):

It's because you can't use git clone in IDLE.
To clone a git repository you should open a terminal and go the location in which you want to clone the repo, and then type the following command:
`git clone https://github.com/marksgraham/OCT-Converter.git`
If it still give you an error then you need to install git, for Mac you can use [this installer](https://sourceforge.net/projects/git-osx-installer/).